# Ruby. Says full_description is undefined even though it's defined in the child class Room. How do I fix this?

Tags: ruby, methods, call, subclass

```
class Dungeon
  attr_accessor :player

  def initialize(player_name)
    @player = Player.new(player_name)
    @rooms = []
  end

  def add_room(reference, name, description, connections)
    @rooms << Room.new(reference, name, description, connections)
  end

  def start(location)
    @player.location = location
    show_current_description
  end

  def show_current_description

    puts find_room_in_dungeon(@player.location).full_description
  end

  def find_room_in_dungeon(reference)
    @rooms.detect { |room| room.reference == reference}
  end

  def find_room_in_direction(direction)
    find_room_in_dungeon(@player.location).connections[direction]
  end

  def go(direction)
    puts "You go " + direction.to_s
    @player.location = find_room_in_direction(direction)
    show_current_description
  end

  class Player
    attr_accessor :name, :location

    def initialize(name)
      @name = name
    end
  end

  class Room
    attr_accessor :reference, :name, :description, :connections

    def initialize(reference, name, description, connections)
      @reference = reference
      @name = name
      @description = description
      @connections = connections
    end

    def full_description
      @name + "\n\nYou are in " + @description
    end
  end

end

# Create the main dungeon object
my_dungeon = Dungeon.new("Freed Bloggs")

# Add rooms to the Dungeon
my_dungeon.add_room(:largecae, "Large Cave", "a large cavernous cave", {:west => :smallcave})
my_dungeon.add_room(:smallcave, "Small Cave", "a small, claustrophobic cave", {:east => :largecave})

# Start the dungeon by placing the player in the large cave
my_dungeon.start(:largecave)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, your problem amounts to a typo:

```
my_dungeon.add_room(:largecae, "Large Cave", "a large cavernous cave", {:west => :smallcave})
```

You've added a room named `:largecae` and then called `my_dungeon.start(:largecave)`—note the missing "v" in the first name.

When `show_current_description` calls `find_room_in_dungeon(@player.location)` the result is `nil`, so you're calling `full_description` on `nil`.

Teaching a man to fish, simply running the code and looking at the full error leads to the answer:

```
$ ruby /tmp/test.rb
/tmp/test.rb:19:in `show_current_description': undefined method `full_description' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from /tmp/test.rb:15:in `start'
        from /tmp/test.rb:69:in `<main>'
```

Note that the error is telling you that `full_description` is undefined for `nil`, not for `Room`.